# Firebase Storage Write Access does not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, cors, firebase-storage

We have a platform that allows users view and sign a document. We did this using firebase storage `getSignedUrl` to create an array `[document with read access, document with write access]`.

The issue we have is that we keep getting a CORS error. We have set the cors configuration on the Google console a couple of times but we still get the same error.[image: CORS error]

Is there a way to solve this issue? An example of this can be replicated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSSC6.png) if you try and sign the document

Below is my config configuration:

```
[
    {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET","PUT", "HEAD"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
    ]
```

I have provided the preflight headers below[image]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[image]

[image]

Latest error is below. The firebase rules have been set (for testing purposes) to allow read and write but we still get this 403 error:[image]

Comment: You write that you've configured CORS, but have you allowed the `PUT` method in your CORS config? It looks like you should for things to work as expected.

Comment: @jub0bs I did. I have added my cors configuration on the question

Comment: Please show what the preflight request looks like (headers and all) in your browser's Network tab.

Comment: @jub0bs just added it in. Thanks

Comment: That's not the preflight request, but the actual request.

Comment: @jub0bs I just added another screen grab. Sorry I am new to cors and requests. Would this be the preflight?

Comment: No... Please pay attention to the "Type" column.

Comment: See that `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header? It tells you that you need to allow request-header name `Content-Type` in your CORS configuration. After that, things should work.

Comment: @DejiJames just change your cors config to also have `"header":"content-type"`

Comment: @jub0bs  @kola I still got the same error. I changed my cors.json to be :

`[
    {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET","PUT", "HEAD"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600,
    "header":["Content-Type"]

    }
    ]`

Comment: It appears that the name of the relevant config field is (inexplicably!) [`responseHeader`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket), not `header`. Try again.

Comment: @jub0bs thank you. I thik it solved the initial issue but another just popped up. :( I just added it in the question.

Comment: Well, please don't move the goal post. Ask about your new issue in a new question. I'm not sure I'll be able to help you this time, because the new issue seems unrelated to CORS.